# How to change a FeatureLayer's symbols?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, feature-layer

I did this:

```
dojo.connect(featureLayer, "onUpdateEnd", function() {
        var defaultSymbol = new esri.symbol.SimpleMarkerSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([0,0,255]));
        dojo.forEach(this.graphics, function(graphic){
                graphic.setSymbol(defaultSymbol);
            });
});
```

I'm not satisfied with this solution because when I add new features to the layer they are added with a default symbol (black circle). Do you know how to set up symbols for the layer once and for all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [renderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/renderer-amd.html). In your case, a [SimpleRenderer](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/simplerenderer-amd.html) is probably ideal. There are several samples that demonstrate this...the [Unique Value Renderer sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/renderer_unique_value.html) is one.

Comment: The links are broken :(